# Yandex MapKit 3 UserLocationLayer иконка "Я" меняется на треуголник

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

Использую карту яндекса версии 3.1.2 в Андройд приложении. Показываю местоположение пользователя. Круглая зеленая иконка с буквой "я" периодически меняется на желтую стрелку. С чем это связано, с каким событием? Можно ли как-то это отключить или заменить иконку "стрелка"?

Comment: Так там обновление вышло 3.2.0 + пример обновили, который вы используете

Comment: @iFr0z о каком примере речь? Можно ссылку?

Comment: Ну я лишь предположил, т.к. код Вы не выложили:) https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo

Comment: А вообще дело в том, что если не указать какая будет иконка для показа местоположения пользователя, то будет отображаться зеленая иконка "Я".  А желтая стрелочка - это картинка формата png, которая находится в Вашем проекте, а именно в drawable. Вы можете поменять на другую картинку или использовать Bitmap. Советую Bitmap.

Comment: iFr0z, спасибо! Это то, что нужно.

Comment: @iFr0z Спасибо! В моем случае иконка не применялась именно потому, что я использовал векторный формат иконки, а надо было растровый. Видимо, mapKit не умеет векторные иконки отрисовывать

Answer (score 4):

Спасибо, iFr0z, пример с github очень помог. 
Отвечу подробнее для тех, кто интересуется этим вопросом. Нужно реализовать UserLocationObjectListener в активити с картой и установить подходящие изображения:

```
    public class UserLocationActivity extends Activity implements 
    UserLocationObjectListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onObjectAdded(UserLocationView userLocationView) {
    userLocationLayer.setAnchor(
            new PointF((float)(mapView.getWidth() * 0.5), (float) 
   (mapView.getHeight() * 0.5)),
            new PointF((float)(mapView.getWidth() * 0.5), (float) 
   (mapView.getHeight() * 0.83)));

    userLocationView.getArrow().setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(
            this, R.drawable.user_arrow));

    CompositeIcon pinIcon = userLocationView.getPin().useCompositeIcon();

    pinIcon.setIcon(
            "icon",
            ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.icon),
            new IconStyle().setAnchor(new PointF(0f, 0f))
                    .setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE)
                    .setZIndex(0f)
                    .setScale(1f)
    );

    pinIcon.setIcon(
            "pin",
            ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.search_result),
            new IconStyle().setAnchor(new PointF(0.5f, 0.5f))
                    .setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE)
                    .setZIndex(1f)
                    .setScale(0.5f)
    );

    userLocationView.getAccuracyCircle().setFillColor(Color.BLUE);
    }  

   ...

  }
```